# can not resolve getActivity() and getApplicationContext()

Tags: android, android-studio

I am learning android from [Android Tutorial for Beginners 8 # wrap_content, fill_parent, Password Field and Toast in Android](https://youtu.be/V7HPQ6DVvug?list=PLS1QulWo1RIbb1cYyzZpLFCKvdYV_yJ-E) 
using android studio 2.2.2.

I have done the same as mentioned in tutorial but unable to understand why getApplicationContext() and getActivity methods are not resolvable.

I have tried getActivity(), getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.this.... etc. But Toast.makeText method unable to recognize Context.

Can anyone please tell me what is the exact issue? and how can I resolve it?

**Below is my code:**

```
package com.example.programingknowledge.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText pass_word;
private Button btn_sbm;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {
    pass_word = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    btn_sbm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final CharSequence passText = pass_word.getText().toString();


    btn_sbm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  passText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.programingknowledge.myfirstapp">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.programingknowledge.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
android:background="@android:color/black">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/editText" />

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is the package name ?

Comment: getActivity()  will work in fragments

Comment: `getActivity()` makes no sense for an Activity. It's already an Activity. And for `getApplicationContext()`, it's better if you use your Activity Context: `this`.

Comment: `MainActivity.this` should work and as said above `getActivity` only works in fragment

Comment: If I use `MainActivity.this` then it shows "Cannot resolve method makeText(com.example.programingknowledge.myfirstapp.MainActivity, java.lang.CharSequence, int)"

Comment: problem is with `passtext`, do `passText.toString()`

Comment: HI All, When I tried to view source of makeText method during that Android studio asked me to update source for android-25. I have downloaded and updated the same. After restart studio it started working. I don't understand the issue but it is solved now. Just want want tell one thing, there is not always same solution for same problem. Cause may change.

Answer (score 5):

Just change getApplicationContext() or getContext() to YourActivity.this

For example

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  passText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Please do not store context as a field. You are able to get in from any point, without storing.

Comment: If I use MainActivity.this then it shows "Cannot resolve method makeText(com.example.programingknowledge.myfirstapp.MainActi‌​vity, java.lang.CharSequence, int)"

Comment: Its because of your passText is CharSequence, use passText.toString()

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I tried to view source of makeText method, during that Android studio asked me to update source for android-25. I have downloaded and updated the same. After restarting studio it's working. I don't understand the issue but it is solved now. It looks like in my app's build.gradle file was compileSdkVersion 25, but I didn't downloaded it.

Comment: I think it is better to store Context as a field becouse it is much easier then to debug it if you have a memoryleak. This line of code has reference to instance of MainActivity anyway.

Answer (score 2):

When you are in Activity that means you have the Context i.e. the Activity. You can achieve this by calling **this** or **MainActivity.this**. As you are using the Toast inside the OnClickListener object **this** will not work here because here **this** means it will take OnClickLister as its object. So here you must use your class.this i.e **MainActivity.this**.
In case of Fragment you can achieve context by Calling **getActivity()** because Fragment must have at least a Activity which is the Context. 
And the **getApplicationContext()** means your whole Application Context.

```
btn_sbm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  passText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you're trying to show a toast from a callback. You should pass the `MainActivity.this` as context in the makeToast method:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  passText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btn_sbm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  passText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  passText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The above should work. If not, post your Logcat for the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Please, post your `AndroidManifest.xml` and `activity_main.xml` files.

Upd.:  The problem is that in your app's `build.gradle` file was compileSdkVersion 25, but you don't download it. Also you should always download android-sdk sources according to your targetSdkversion. So, just keep your Android Studio files current and that problems should go away.

Comment: I can't see what's wrong. Try this:
FIle -> Invalidate Caches/Restart
and Build -> Rebuild Project.

Comment: When I tried to view source of makeText method during that Android studio asked me to update source for android-25. I have downloaded and updated the same. After restart studio it started working. I don't understand the issue but it is solved now.

Comment: It looks like in your app's build.gradle file was compileSdkVersion 25, but you don't download it. So, just keep your Android Studio files current and that problems should go away.

Comment: You should always download android-sdk sources according to your targetSdkversion.